# Forbidden characters in TCP/IP

Tags: esp8266, tcpip

I'm trying to send data from my ESP8266 to a NodeJS TCP server, the connection and basic charakters (48-90) are working fine, but if I use others like ASCII-Code (0,1,2,3...)  I don't get any usefull data out of it. So what I was thinking about that there are some character which aren't allowed to send over TCP/IP.

By the way,
I'm using this to write to the server, and I work with the standard WiFi Client library

```
char arr[255]
for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
   arr[i] = (char)i;
}
client.print(arr);
```

Nodejs File:

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

var mysql = require('mysql');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];
var uploadCounter = 0;

initMySQLConnection();


// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {


    // Identify this client
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort

    // Put this new client in the list
    clients.push(socket);

    // Send a nice welcome message and announce
    socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
    broadcast(socket.name + " connected\n", socket);

    // Handle incoming messages from clients.
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        broadcast(">> " + data, socket);

        uploadData(data);
    });

    // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
    socket.on('end', function () {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        broadcast(socket.name + " disconnected.\n\n");
    });

    // Send a message to all clients
    function broadcast(message, sender) {
        clients.forEach(function (client) {
            // Don't want to send it to sender
            if (client === sender) return;
            //client.write(message);
        });
        // Log it to the server output too
        process.stdout.write(message)
    }

}).listen(10101);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 10101\n");


var connection;
function initMySQLConnection() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "host",
        user: "user",
        password: "pass",
        database: "database"
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {              
        if (err) {                                     
            console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
        }                                    
    });  

    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('db error', err);
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
                                    // lost due to either server restart, or a
        } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
            throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
        }
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        connection.query('SELECT 1');
    }, 60000);
}

function uploadData(data) {
    data = String(data);

    console.log("Package Length: " + data.length);
    console.log("GOT ASCII CODE: ");
    for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        console.log(data.charCodeAt(i));
    }


    //upload Code
}
```

Comment: what does this mean? ... `I don't get any usefull data out of it`  ................ what are you expecting for `ASCII-Code (0,1,2,3...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function takes an array of characters as zero terminated c-string. It prints until a byte with value 0. You have zero at `arr[0]` so it is an empty string.

To send bytes, `write` function is used. The `print` functions convert parameters to text or expect text as zero terminated char array.

In your case it should be `client.write(arr, length);` where `length` is the number of bytes you want to send from the buffer `arr`.

Comment: now I get values from 0-127 but all above is 65533. so the error seems to be in my nodejs file, i will add it above

Comment: ASCII code are only until 127. why do you read it as String and chars?

Comment: Doesnt the extended ascii code go until 255?

Comment: tell it to data.charCodeAt(i) :-)

Comment: So you mean without the data = String(data)?

Comment: try ArrayBuffer